# NSAttributedString alignment not working on html content

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

Want to change alignment of html label. Nothing works. I don't see any CSS in the HTML. There are no further settings changing the alignment. I also set left alignment directly on the UILabel. What am I missing?

The code is in UILabel extension.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

NSDictionary *attr = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,  NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};
NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:attr documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

// also tried with this
[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle
                           range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)
     ];

self.attributedText = attributedText;
```

**Edit**

Ok, so I created a separate project and there, the text is left aligned by default. I have to find out why in above example the text shows justified. In any case, the main problem remains, I can't change the default alignment. It works when initializing the attributed string with `initWithString`. But in this case html doesn't work. When `initWithData`, like in above example, html works but alignment does not work.

Run this snippet and you will see.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 400);
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

NSString *text = @"sfsf sldjfs fj <b>dsfjslf</b> dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkfsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkflsfsf sldjfs fj dsfjslf dsfslkf jsfsfjsdkfll END";

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
NSDictionary *attr = @{
                       NSFontAttributeName: font,
                       NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                       NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding), 
                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};
NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:attr documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

[attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

NSLog(@"err: %@", error);

label.attributedText = attributedText;

[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Edit 2:

Case 1 - solved - I somewhere later in the code alignment was being changed. Didn't see that.

Case 2 - solved - see answer.

Comment: @ Ixx  is it working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that as said by the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:) `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` only accept 3 possibles keys: `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute`, `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute` and `NSDefaultAttributesDocumentAttribute`.

Then, with your snippet, you didn't applied the `NSParagraphStyleAttributedName` at the end like in your previous attempt.

So, from your snippet, I put this line instead:

```
[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                       value:paragraphStyle
                       range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];
```

And removed the 2 useless attributed from `attr`:

```
NSDictionary *attr = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                       NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution. I assume the alignment doesn't work because it expects this kind of attributes in the html. So I added it to the html:

```
text = [@"<style> p {text-align: right;}</style><body>" stringByAppendingFormat:@"<p>%@</p></body>", text];
```

Works with center, left, etc.