# NSAttributed string with `center` tag is not working

Tags: html, ios, iphone, nsattributedstring

I am trying to set NSAttributed string to UILabel by passing string check the method below :

```
-(NSAttributedString *) returnRichTextForString:(NSString *) inputString {

   NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:  NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
   NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
   [paragrahStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
   [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])];
   return attributedString; 
}
```

And I gave input string as  : 
`@"<body> <p>This is some text.</p> <center>This text will be center-aligned.</center> <p>This is some other text. </p> </body>";`

I was expecting text within `<center>...</center>` tag to be center aligned. But it's not happening!. Any way other than CSS ?

> Anyway I don't want to set `NSTextAlignmentCenter` attribute to
>   UILabel.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html  I got know that `<center>` tag is removed in HTML5. Hence this issue !?

Comment: See the Link 1 . http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/create-nsattributedstring-html-ios-7.html  2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816501/nsattributedstring-alignment-not-working-on-html-content

Comment: Able to fix by this replacement : `<div style="text-align:center">...</div>` for `<center>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by replacing `<center>` tag with

`<div style="text-align:center">...</div>`

**from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)**,  **is no more supported in HTML5**

[image]